# ConvertTo between EntityFramework Models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, mapping

I have a model called `EditModel`, and a model called `EditHistoryModel`, I want to capture the save on every transaction. They share the same schema.

To persist/Update, I am doing the following in the Edit [PostAction] of the controller.

```
 EditController...
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Update Edit status in Edit table
            db.Entry(EditTable).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //**update Edit 1** Add new Record Transaction (History) in history table
            db.Entry((EditTable) as EditHistory).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            // **the cast is not working???*********
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");               
        }
```

1. Can you help me if there is an easy way to map the to tables as history or journaling, since they are the same schema?
2. Is there something I need to configure in EF?
3. How can I ensure these both models are atomic together, *both succeed or both fail* on roll back if needed

Update Edit 1: On the second table **its not update, but a new record is being added**. i.e Add new Record Transaction (History) in history table

Comment: By your explanation, 2 tables can share an identic row values, is that correct? If so, I would suggest to make additional model to save that row and, EditModel and EditHistoryModel can have single reference to it.

Comment: @NugrohoBudi you made me realize a small error, in my question. You're right, the second table is an `Add` to the `EditHistory` table, while the first is simply an `Update` to the record.